# Не получается запустить скрипт - проблема с import re

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Всем добра! Понадобился скрипт на питоне запустить, опыта ноль. Установил питон 3.8.8 (т.к. вин7, выше не дает установить версию, требует вин8+), установил библиотеку whois. Пытаюсь запустить скрипт

```
import whois
        import re
        f = open('3.txt')
        s = f.readline()
        while(s):
            s = re.sub("^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$", '', s)
            print(s)
            try:
                m = whois.whois(s)

                print("Домен занят")
            except:
                print("Домен свободен")

            finally:
                print("------------------------------")
                s = f.readline()
```

Но выдает ошибку (извиняюсь за скрин, но окно сразу закрывается, еле поймал)

[image: Ошибка при запуске скрипта]

Пробовал установить re, выдает ошибку. Установил regex, пробовал import regex, тоже самое выдает. Дальше не знаю куда копать.

Пробовал менять адрес файла с доменами (3.txt) на полный или абсолютный путь, но ошибка та же самая с import re.

С пробелами разобрался, теперь такая ситуация, ничего не происходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте сделать самую очевидную вещь — прочитать текст ошибки. В ней написано, что у вас неправильный отступ. Зачем вы перед `import re` поставили отступ?

Comment: andreymal, спасибо, я даже и не думал, что отступы имеют значение, т.к. в основном имею дело с html, css, php, там отступы не имеют такого значения, больше визуальное) Проработал все отступы, где не надо убрал, где надо добавил. Последняя ошибка была с путём файла с доменами, поменял слэши на на /, и в итоге скрипт запускается без ошибок, но и ничего не происходит. Загрузил скрин в основной пост

Comment: Ничего не происходит, потому что в вашем последнем варианте цикл `while(s)` является вечным и никогда не завершится

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Python большую роль играют отступы, а у вас они стоя не правильно. Вот как должно быть:

```py
import whois
import re


f = open('3.txt')
s = f.readline()

while(s):
    s = re.sub("^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$", '', s)
    print(s)
    
    try:
        m = whois.whois(s)
        print("Домен занят")
    except:
        print("Домен свободен")
    finally:
        print("------------------------------")
        s = f.readline()
```

Comment: Спасибо больше, процесс пошёл, проверка идёт)) Век живи - век учись, буду знать про такие нюансы с отступами

Comment: Пожалуйста, если вы считаете что ответ вам помог отметьте его как верный.